# Hyphen vs. En Dash vs. Em Dash to split a clause

Tags: hyphens

Which one should I use to split a clause like in the example below?

> Go to `Preferences > Settings – Syntax Specific`.

[image]

The screenshot above shows [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com) menu.

I'm sure they did not use the hyphen.
I've gone through the [www.thepunctuationguide.com](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com) guide but I haven't found this case.

Anyway, apart from what they used, which one is correct?

Other options are listed in the [UTF-8 General Punctuation](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp) table.

---

I also noticed StackExchange is using the En Dash in the comments (before the author). Many others, including [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-blockquotes), are using the Em Dash.

Comment: A M-dash (em-dash) is used in the image. An en-dash looks almost like a hyphen.

Comment: I believe the "em dash," as stated in your title, is correct. In Microsoft Word, for instance, typing two hyphens "--" is automatically corrected to an em dash. Here in ELL, it may not work. Let's see: "I went to work -- wait, I forgot my keys this morning." As an editor, I would know that your use of a double hyphen meant an em dash. I agree with @SovereignSun that the en-dash is a *typographical* hyphen.

Comment: @MarkHubbard I didn't know about two hyphens. It works in LibreOffice as well. Nice tip!

Comment: @SovereignSun I think it depends by the font: Here is the sequence: ‐ – ―. As you can see the hyphen (the first one) looks different from the en-dash (the second). This is how they look with a different font: `‐ – ―`.

Comment: @MarkHubbard You can use `&mdash;` to create an em-dash on ELL. (It may not work in comments.)

Comment: @MarkHubbard The en-dash (–) is not a *typographical* hyphen (‐). Please read my previous comment: the en-dash looks more like an em-dash (―).

Comment: Thank you for correcting me; I appreciate it! And thank you @user178049 for the tip -- I'm always happy to learn something new! (Neither &mdash; nor U-2015 is working for me -- Isar, what am I doing wrong?)

Comment: @MarkHubbard That's the spirit! The entity code doesn't work in comments. You can copy the punctuation directly from an HTML Unicode table since UTF-8 is supported. A link to the table is above in my updated question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://ux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @BenKovitz My question has nothing to do with UX. The Sublime Text screenshot is there just to show the contest of the clause. The question is about english punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

From this source [Grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/grammar/emdash/):

> An **em dash** (**—**) is longer than an **en dash** (**–**) and three times as long as a **hyphen** (**-**).
>
> Uses of the **em dash**:
>
> 1. **Em dashes** set apart parenthetical phrases or clauses in a sentence. In this use, **em dashes** are similar to *commas* and *parentheses*.
>
>    - Since 2007, the consensus of the economic establishment—bankers, policymakers, CEOs, stock analysts, pundits—has been catastrophically wrong.
> 2. An **em dash** can indicate a sudden break, an interruption, or a trailing off.
>
>    - HOWARD:  …  She’s totally unapologetic, she’s—
>    - CHEW-BOSE: She’s everything.
> 3. **Em dashes** can replace colons or serve as harder versions of commas *(similar to semicolons)*.
>
>    - The all-renewable energy sector is 30 years away — and always will be.
>    - It’s that time of year again—time for New Year’s Resolutions!

The **en dash** is most commonly used to indicate inclusive dates and numbers. ([**Source**](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/091502enem.htm))

The most common versions of the dash are the **en dash** (**–**) and the longer **em dash** (**—**), whose names historically were loosely related with the length of a *lower-case n* and *upper-case M*, respectively, in commonly used typefaces.

> **U+2015** ― **Horizontal bar**, also known as a **quotation dash**, is used to introduce quoted text. This is the standard method of printing dialogue in some languages. The **em dash** is equally suitable if the **quotation dash** is unavailable or is contrary to the house style being used.

This article may be interesting: [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)
[image]

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Clare It does, the em dash splits clauses and it's written in the uses block.